# Script runs pv command on remote host - all output displays locally as expected, except the pv progress bar

Tags: bash, pv

The command executed remotely goes as follows,

`cat ${DUMPFILE} | pv -ls $( wc -l ${DUMPFILE} ) | gzip -c -- > ${DUMPFILE_ZIPPED}`

`pv` shows progress as expected when script is executed from host.

Is there a way to have `pv` output show, when executed remotely?

Comment: @Poshi - The reason for the `wc` call is that the wc call makes the pv progress bar more accurate on ETA.  In my humble opinion a call to wc on a 10GO file is minimal and I can deal with the "overhead" it incurs in exchange for more precise ETA.

Comment: the point is that with my simplified solution you get the same acurateness and avoid the extra file read. Also the command is simpler and clearer.

Comment: When you say "executed remotely", what do you mean? Which is the code to start the remote execution?

Comment: Can you explain what us "not working"?